# Database of powered mobility device (wheelchairs, etc) activity logs?

Tags: data-request, medical, transportation

I would like to know if there exists a publicly accessible collection of activity logs of powered mobility device usage by elderly/disabled individuals.

Specific contents I'm after are user input data such as joysticks etc, and location information in Cartesian co-ordinates or in some representation convertible into a Cartesian co-ordinate system.